# Не меняется значение на выходе из функции

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Описано два класса в одном пекедже. В первом описание объекта и методы, в другом эти методы должны выполняться. В первом классе описан метод, который должен задавать значение полям– при выводе значений a и b внутри функции все работает так, как и планировалось. Но при выводе `a.trait,`b.trait`в теле`main`значения`a.trait`,`b.trait` равны нулю. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public class Person {
        int trait;
        public static void input(int a, int b){...}
}


public class Thing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Person a = new Person();
        Person b = new Person();
        Person.input(a.trait, b.trait);
    }
}
```

Comment: в передаче параметров по значению

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует два основных метода передачи параметров: вызов по значению (*pass-by-value*) и вызов по ссылке (*pass-by-reference*). В Java, для передачи параметров (как примитивных типов, **так и ссылочных**) используется первый метод – **вызов по значению**.

В случае *pass-by-value*, значение аргумента копируется в формальный параметр метода.

---

Вы передаете в метод два параметра **примитивного типа**, далее в методе Вы работаете с копиями переданных значений, а изменение копии переданного аргумента (примитивного типа) никоим образом не влечет за собой изменение оригиналов.

В случае передачи аргументов **объектного типа**, в метод передается копия ссылки, и, следовательно, изменения объекта внутри метода влияют на объект, который используется в качестве аргумента.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у объектов а и b конструктор без аргументов, значит их поля traint равны нулю, соответственно ты и передаёшь нули в метод input. Соответственно вам надо или назначить их после создания объекта, или сделать конструктор где эти переменные зададутся